# Is theere any way of using noconflict for a file

Tags: jquery

I wonder is there anyway to use `jQuery.noconflict` for whole file without editing the file itself ?

I mean something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
 </script>
```

and then put the path to the file which contains `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
 <script src="http://www.domain.com/script.min.js"></script>
```

So in my mind it would like like

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> - opens noconflict 
var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();   - the variable 
  <script src="http://www.domain.com/script.min.js"></script> - the file which should use the variable
 </script> - closing noconflict
```

Is it possible :) ? 
Thanks for any suggestions, my problem is, I don't have access to these files, and i need to make them works. Because now, it alerts `jQuery is not a function`  so its not declared anywhere I guess ;)

Comment: Script elements can not be nested, and calling a jQuery method before jQuery is embedded will of course not work. And unclear what you mean by _“without editing the file itself”_ – is putting differen Script elements into the document _not_ “editing” it …? How to use `noConflict` is described in the docs, so what is the actual problem left here that you’re trying to solve …?

Comment: I dont have access to ftp , so i dont have access to the script itself, and trying to do something via admin panel, with header.php file ;)